# How do I remove an array of referenced Objects when deleting the main document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

This is my MongoDB schema:

```
const MenuSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  caterer: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  products: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product'
  }]
}, { timestamps: true })


const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  price: {
    type: String
  }
}, { timestamps: true })
```

What I'm wondering - is how I can delete the array of products, at the same time as I delete the main "Menu" document? When I remove the `Menu`, I can also assume that the `products` belonging to the menu should be removed.

At the moment this is how I remove the menu (and tried to remove its products):

```
await Menu.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.menu_id }, (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      Product.remove({ _id: { $in: req.body.products }}, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
        console.log('Deleted products');
      });
    });
```

However, the products do not get removed. Any suggestions?

Comment: `Product.remove({ _id: req.body.products })` is enough, but make sure it's array of ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose provides a pre and post middleware on your schema. Which means you can delete all the referenced documents before or after you do an operation on the current schema.

**Read more [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html).**

Here's an example, inside your schema add this:

```
const MenuSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  caterer: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  products: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product'
  }]
}, { timestamps: true })


const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  price: {
    type: String
  }
}, { timestamps: true })


MenuSchema.post('remove', removeProducts);

function removeProducts(doc) {
   Products.remove({_id: { $in: doc.products}})
}
```

**Assuming Products is the name of your model.**

Answer (score 0):

Try This It works for Me.

```
await Menu.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.menu_id }, (err, response) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  Product.remove({ _id: { $in: response.products }}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    console.log('Deleted products');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use post schema hooks of mongoose as below

```
schema.post('remove', function(doc) {
  console.log('%s has been removed', doc._id);
});
```

[Mongoose Post Hook](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post)

But the best approach is to use transactions to execute multiple operations on the database as below.

```
let session = null;
db.startSession()
.then((_session) =>{
    session = _session;
    session.startTransaction();
    return Menu.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.menu_id });
})
.then(()=> Product.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: req.body.products }}))
.then(()=>{
    session.commitTransaction();
})
.catch((err)=>{
    session.abortTransaction()
    return handleError(err);
})
```

[Mongoose Transactions](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html)